# Gradle cannot resolve symbol while it does

Tags: gradle, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I've the following build.gradle file:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.FatFrameworkTask

apply plugin: 'kotlin-multiplatform'
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test'
    testImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit'
    testImplementation 'com.google.truth:truth:0.42'

    androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.google.truth:truth:0.42'
}

kotlin {
    targets {
        jvm("jvm")
        android("android")
        iosArm32("ios32")
        iosArm64("ios64")
        iosX64("emulator")

        configure([ios32, ios64, emulator]) {
            binaries.framework('HyModule')
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        commonMain.dependencies {
            api 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common'
        }
        jvmMain.dependencies {
            api 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8'
        }
        androidMain.dependencies {
            implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib'
        }
        androidMain.dependsOn jvmMain
    }

    task fatFramework(type: FatFrameworkTask) {
        // the fat framework must have the same base name as the initial frameworks
        baseName = "HyModule"

        final File frameworkDir = new File(buildDir, "xcode-frameworks")
        destinationDir = frameworkDir

        // specify the frameworks to be merged
        from(
                targets.ios32.binaries.getFramework('HyModule', 'RELEASE'),
                targets.ios64.binaries.getFramework('HyModule', 'RELEASE'),
                targets.emulator.binaries.getFramework('HyModule', 'RELEASE')
        )

        doLast {
            new File(frameworkDir, 'gradlew').with {
                text = "#!/bin/bash\nexport 'JAVA_HOME=${System.getProperty("java.home")}'\ncd '${rootProject.rootDir}'\n./gradlew \$@\n"
                setExecutable(true)
            }
        }
    }
}

// workaround for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-27170
configurations {
    compileClasspath
}

tasks.build.dependsOn fatFramework
```

`import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.FatFrameworkTask` is marked in red with an error

> Cannot resolve symbol 'FatFrameworkTask'

Even though everything works just fine, I don't like having error in my project.

Comment: Consider using Gradle Kotlin DSL instead of Groovy scripts – it has somewhat better IDE support, including type & calls checking and code completion.

Comment: Have you manage to solve this? I have same problem using build.gradle.kts and compiling with gradle.

Comment: @Pavel sadly no

Comment: Seems this import is missing in 1.3.21. But it is in 1.3.30

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.*
```

I was facing same problem, 
Don't know why this works

Answer (score 0):

If the Gradle Task is working fine can be a visual bug in IntelliJ, this happens normally with me.

Try to restart the IntelliJ or Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

In my case, don't use import, use class full path instead, for ex, following `org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile`

```
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile) {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = ['-Xjsr305=strict']
        jvmTarget = '17'
    }
}
```